# Trouble changing UIButton image

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

I have a tableView in which i post users feeds and i added a heart button for like in the cell view. I created a class for the cell view and declared my `@IBOutlet` of the button there. Then in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in the tableview i called the button and made the `indexpath.row` the tag number of the button itself. Then i added a target with an action to be done and created my `@IBAction`. Now I'm trying to change the image look of the heart button to red but nothing happens. Is there a problem passing the an UIImage to the button via the sender. I have no errors. And the `if like =` statement is working correctly. Here is my code:

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PostsCellTableViewCell

        cell.heartButton.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.heartButton.addTarget(self, action: "liked:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
return cell
}

@IBAction func liked (sender: UIButton){

        if like == false{
        sender.imageView?.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: "red-heart.png")
            like = true
        }
        else{
            sender.imageView?.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: "white-heart-hi.png")
            like = false
        }
       // self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead.

```
    if like == false{
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "red-heart.png"), forState: .Normal)
        like = true
    } else {
        sender.setImage.setImage(UIImage(named: "white-heart-hi.png"), forState: .Normal)
        like = false
    }
```

Comment: Sweet. Glad I could be of assistance. Whenever you get a chance, accepting this answer would be awesome.

Answer (score -1):

This is a really simple error. You declared your target function as "liked:", but your function is declared as "liked". Notice the lack of a colon the second time. This is critical, and should fix the problem. If this does not fix the problem, make sure you have declared

```
var like = false
```

If this still doesn't work, comment and I will continue helping. If it does work, don't forget to check my answer.

Comment: The selector corresponding to Kegham's `liked(_:)` function is `liked:` with a colon.

Comment: See [Interacting with Objective-C APIs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID35) for more information.

Comment: var like = false is declared globally. I sad i have no errors. I cannot remove the column. I will get an error.